# Tableau filtering with calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

I have  calculated Z Score at row level following way.

```
AVG = window_avg(sum(measure))
STDEV = window_stdevp(sum(measure)
ZSCORE = (sum(measure) - AVG) / STDEVP
```

This works nicely and I have zscore for each row if data is aggregated at the level. I would now like to aggregate my data to monthly but exclude all the rows outside of -2 - 2 zscore range. When I add zscore to filter, it is already at monthly level and won't filter individual rows.

How can I change this so aggregation only includes rows with correct zscore?

Comment: Have you tried using LODs? https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm

Comment: I haven’t, looks like that will do it, but my version 2020.4 (company policy) won’t have that yet. I will keep that in mind in year 2022 when we get that update.